# Javascript - how can I make this recursive?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a function to render comments, in which each comment is stored as an object in an array. Comments can have reply comments, in which they have the exact same html and data to render, just their styling is different (via a CSS modifier class).

How can I make this function **recursive**? The `renderReplies(comment.replies)` calls a function that is the exact same as `renderComments` function, just without the mentioned function call `renderReplies` (as a reply to a reply is the exact same also in styling terms).

```
const renderComments = (comments) => {
    commentsElement.innerHTML = '';
    comments.forEach(comment => {
        commentsElement.innerHTML += html;

        // data-id attribute
        const liElements = commentsElement.querySelectorAll('.comment');
        const liElement = liElements.item(liElements.length - 1);
        liElement.setAttribute('data-id', comment.id);

        // author
        liElement.querySelector('.comment__author').innerHTML = comment.user.username;

        // avatar src & alt attributes
        const avatar = liElement.querySelector('.comment__avatar');
        avatar.setAttribute('src', comment.user.image.png);
        avatar.setAttribute('alt', comment.user.username);

        // time since posted

        // content
        const p = liElement.querySelector('.comment__text');
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(comment.content));

        // score
        liElement.querySelector('.comment__score b').innerHTML = comment.score;

        // replies
        renderReplies(comment.replies);
    });
};
```

Comment: Are they really identical except for the call at the end? If `renderReplies` also begins with `commentsElement.innerHTML = '';`, doesn't it wipe out all the previous comments and replies?

Comment: @Barmar I did forget to mention that part. I don't feel like repeating all that code because of two small differences is the optimal solution, it's bugging me lol

Comment: The simplest way to deal with that is to empty `commentsElement` *before* calling this function instead of doing it in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether there's a `replies` property. If it exists, call the function recursively. Since replies won't have replies of their own, you'll stop there.

```
const renderComments = (comments) => {
    commentsElement.innerHTML = '';
    comments.forEach(comment => {
        commentsElement.innerHTML += html;

        // data-id attribute
        const liElements = commentsElement.querySelectorAll('.comment');
        const liElement = liElements.item(liElements.length - 1);
        liElement.setAttribute('data-id', comment.id);

        // author
        liElement.querySelector('.comment__author').innerHTML = comment.user.username;

        // avatar src & alt attributes
        const avatar = liElement.querySelector('.comment__avatar');
        avatar.setAttribute('src', comment.user.image.png);
        avatar.setAttribute('alt', comment.user.username);

        // time since posted

        // content
        const p = liElement.querySelector('.comment__text');
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(comment.content));

        // score
        liElement.querySelector('.comment__score b').innerHTML = comment.score;

        // replies
        if (comment.hasOwnProperty("replies")) {
            renderComments(comment.replies);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: That's perfect! Much appreciated. My tired brain has been trying to solve this for over an hour -_-